# C#: alternative to Resharper, C# version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, resharper

It's not quite cheap for me (149 USD). I tried it and I loved it though. The most cool thing for me is refactoring to LINQ. So I was wondering if there is a cheaper alternative that can do that same - refactor my loops into smaller LINQ ones?

Comment: +1 Just uninstalled resharper trial for the same reason. Cool, but not 300.00 commercial license cool.  Maybe if I learned to use the advanced features it would be worth it, but I can't justify learning more crap for a product that's supposed to make life easier.

Comment: I think ReSharper is worth the money, but a good question anyways.

Comment: You can get the C# edition for $149

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DevXpress Refactor! Pro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) is similar, and is $99 per license.

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/individual-justcode.aspx) also makes a refactoring add-in, but it's more expensive ($199).

If you qualify for an academic license, you can get ReSharper cheaper. They even offer free licenses for Open Source projects.

Comment: I have to point out that I've tried Refactor! Pro and it does tend to be a little buggy and slow. It's great, and works most of the time, but recently I stopped paying for the subscription and have gone back to stock Visual Studio. It stinks that I'm missing out of the tools it provides, but it's nice to have a fast, reliable Visual Studio again. Note: Never tried ReSharper.

Comment: ReSharper's definitely worth a trial run. It's one of those things that once you have it you wonder how you programmed without it.

Comment: @Phil: +1. Can't agree more. I like vertical lines but god it makes things crawling!

Comment: @driis: I don't see Refactor! providing loops to LINQ refactoring.

Comment: +1 for mentioning academic and open-source license options -- I always forget about those.

Comment: DevExpress also offers a completely FREE CodeRush Xpress for C# and VB - http://www.devexpress.com/crx

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of questions comparing ReSharper to Refactor! Pro:

[2008: Resharper vs. CodeRush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216/2008-resharper-vs-coderush)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605446/pros-and-cons-of-refactor-vs-resharper